# How can I share common data between Xamarin Form pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Problem:
I'm not sure how to pass common/shared (singleton?) data around to my Xamarin Forms webpages.

Context:
In Xamarin Forms, on the App startup, I'm checking to see if a file exists with the user's login info and some other basic meta data. If not, login, download it and store it onto the device.

Later on in the app (in some `TabbedPages`) I need to access this data.

What do people commonly do, here?

Have some `static` properties somewhere which store this value OR have some services that load this data from the file, when required/on demand?

I thought of passing it through via constructors (hat tip to my use of Dependency Injection from my ASP.NET coding) also but felt this might get a bit manual and verbose.

What patterns are people using/doing, please?

Comment: Static properties/class would make sense or you can use a singleton or if you require specific platform implementations, use the [Dependency Service](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) and register a singleton or maybe the [Messaging Center](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/)? In my project, I used a proper IOC and MVVM pattern and that helped me fixed this type of problems. Might not fit your use case though.